# CocoaPod with local dependency pod install fails

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Not much I can add to this but the below verbose logging when executing pod install using CocoaPods version 1.0.1

> -> Fetching podspec for `mobile-ios-common` from `../mobile-ios-common`
>
> Resolving dependencies of `Podfile` [!] Unable to satisfy the
>   following requirements:
>
> - `mobile-ios-common (from`../mobile-ios-common`)` required by `Podfile`
>
> It seems like you've changed the constraints of dependency
>   `mobile-ios-common` inside your development pod
>   `mobile-ios-common`. You should run `pod update
>   mobile-ios-common` to apply changes you've made.

This same command works on a different app at the same level with the same definition for the mobile-ios-common dependency.  I have tried running `pod deintegrate` and then trying it again without luck.  Not sure how it would be aware of a change if I am basically running it clean.

I did try running `pod update mobile-ios-common` but it then says there is no Podfile.lock and I should then run `pod install`

So question is why is this happening and/or how do I move forward debugging this.

Comment: did you tried to remove you podfile.lock and then run pod update ?

Comment: If you are talking about the Podfile.lock in the App project that is using the mobile-ios-common pod then yes.  pod deintegrate does that.